# Haskell: parse error on input `import'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to recreate the output of [this Haskell code](https://lotz84.github.io/haskellbyexample/ex/for):

```
forM_ = flip mapM_
import Control.Monad.Cont

main = do
    forM_ [1..3] $ \i -> do
        print i

forM_ [7..9] $ \j -> do
    print j

withBreak $ \break ->
    forM_ [1..] $ \_ -> do
        p "loop"
        break ()

where
withBreak = (`runContT` return) . callCC
p = liftIO . putStrLn
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
$ runhaskell for.hs
1
2
3
7
8
9
loop
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 Test4.hs:2:1: parse error on input `import'
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong?

Comment: Imports should come before any other definitions. The `forM_ = flip mapM_` line in that post is not part of the code, so just delete it.

Comment: @duplode That's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: Also, I object to the close votes: this is very much reproducible, and isn't a typo. This seems like a perfectly cromulent (if simple) question to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner Though I was one of the close voters, on second thought there is a decent case for keeping this question, specially given that, perhaps surprisingly, there seem to be no other questions specifically about this error. That being so, I have retracted my vote and will convert the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> Test4.hs:2:1: parse error on input `import'
> ```

The error points to the second line of your file. Quoting the first two lines:

```
forM_ = flip mapM_
import Control.Monad.Cont
```

The problem is that an import declaration must be at the beginning of a module, before any definitions (the only things that can come before an import are language pragmas, such as those used to enable GHC extensions, and the module declaration). In your case, the first line of the file is a definition, and so the misplaced import declaration in the second line leads to a parse error. Since that first line wasn't actually part of the code snippet in the post you linked to, you can simply delete it.